# Search from Multidimentianl array given by a value with array column and get array value

Tags: php

I have an array like the below:

```
$mapLocation = array ( 
  array(
    'county_served'=>'Dhaka',
    'longitude'=>'628',
    'latitude'=>'389'),
  array(
    'county_served'=>'Grand Traverse1',
    'longitude'=>'185',
    'latitude'=>'233'),
  array(
    'county_served'=>'Gogebic', 
    'longitude'=>'73',
    'latitude'=>'205'),
  array(
    'county_served'=>'Gratiot', 
    'longitude'=>'533',
    'latitude'=>'540'),
  array(
    'county_served'=>'Hillsdale', 
    'longitude'=>'536',
    'latitude'=>'686')
);
```

From this array I wanna search by `county_served value` and get that `lngitude` and `latitude value`. I tried by the below code but it dont give my output.

Suppose i searched by Dhaka :

```
if(array_search('Dhaka', array_column($mapLocation, 'county_served')) !== False) { 
    $longitude= $mapLocation['longitude']; 
    $latitude= $mapLocation['latitude']; 
} 
echo $longitude.":".$latitude ;
```

Output will be `628 : 389`.

Hope you got my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try by parsing location by simple `foreach` loop as in code below:

```
$mapLocation = array(
    array(
        'county_served' => 'Dhaka',
        'longitude' => '628',
        'latitude' => '389'),
    array(
        'county_served' => 'Grand Traverse1',
        'longitude' => '185',
        'latitude' => '233'),
    array(
        'county_served' => 'Gogebic',
        'longitude' => '73',
        'latitude' => '205'),
    array(
        'county_served' => 'Gratiot',
        'longitude' => '533',
        'latitude' => '540'),
    array(
        'county_served' => 'Hillsdale',
        'longitude' => '536',
        'latitude' => '686')
);
$latitude = $longitude = '';
foreach ($mapLocation as $value) {
    if ($value["county_served"] == "Dhaka") {
        $latitude = $value["latitude"];
        $longitude = $value["longitude"];
        break;
    }
}
echo "$latitude : $longitude";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
// Create a function to search by 'county_served' so you can use it for each county_served
function getByCountyServed($array, $county_served) {
    // Var if name doesn't exist
    $name_exist = false;
    foreach ($array as $key => $data) {
        // If you find the name : echo the long et lat
        if ($data['county_served'] == $county_served) {
            $name_exist = true;
            echo 'longitude : '. $data['longitude'] ." <br>latitude :  ". $data['latitude'];
            break;
        }
    }
    // If you don't find the name : echo error message
    if (!$name_exist) echo "County Served data not found";
}

getByCountyServed($mapLocation, 'Dhaka');
```

Output is :

```
longitude : 628 
latitude : 389
```

And if you do :

```
getByCountyServed($mapLocation, 'blabla');
```

Output is : `County Served data not found`

Answer (score 0):

You were really close to the solution. You did not saved the index [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) is returning:

```
// Save the index
$index = array_search('Dhaka', array_column($mapLocation, 'county_served'))

if($index !== false) {
    // Use the index as it is a multidimensional array
    $longitude= $mapLocation[$index]['longitude'];
    $latitude= $mapLocation[$index]['latitude'];

    echo $longitude.":".$latitude ;
} else {
    echo "not found";
}
```

From the documentation:

> **Return Values**
>   Returns the key for needle if it is found in the array, FALSE otherwise.

*No real need of a `foreach` loop here, your idea was good.*

Comment: Thanks a  lot..Its working..I thought something was missing but i could not find that. again thanks.